# Base ClearCase failed. exit code=1. IOException: cleartool did not return the expected exit code

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, clearcase

After searching found that to run the selenium test from Jenkins we have to run the jenkins by command **`Java -jar jenkins.war`** instead of as a ***Service***

Problem is that when running the Jenkins as a service it works fine but when running it with the command job is giving error:

```
FATAL: Base ClearCase failed. exit code=1
FATAL: java.io.IOException: cleartool did not return the expected exit code. 
Command line="endview -server sprint8_view_DCLLegacy", actual exit code=1
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\cleartool" endview -server sprint8_view_DCLLegacy
cleartool: Error: Cannot stop view server for view "sprint8_view_DCLLegacy": Permission denied.

FATAL: Base ClearCase failed. exit code=1
java.io.IOException: cleartool did not return the expected exit code. 
Command line="endview -server sprint8_view_DCLLegacy", actual exit code=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check with which account you are running Jenkins as a service:

- the system account
- or a user account.

If a `cleartool enview -server` works in command line, but not from Jenkins running as a service, you need to make sure the service is running with the right account.

> this error wont come from Jenkins running as a service but comes in command line

If it is the opposite, you could create a simple Jenkins job that would close the view you want (using a parameter).
Calling that job would end the view.

Or, in command line, [use `PsExec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), which should launch a session using the LocalSystem acount:

```
C:\>psexec -i -s Powershell.exe

PsExec v1.97 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2009 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

> This will launch a new window.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> whoami
nt authority\system
```

Comment: service is using local system account checked on the log on tab.

Comment: @akshayjain exactly, try using a user account instead of the local system account.

Comment: this error wont come from Jenkins running as a service but comes in command line

Comment: @akshayjain Ok, I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: when we run the Jenkins from java -jar jenkins.war that time it started from with which account??

Comment: if in both the case as a service and by the command java -jar jenkins.war start with the local system account then why it is giving error in the command option??

Comment: @akshayjain no in command line, it uses your account, not a system account

Comment: @akshayjain I have edited my answer to include a way to run a shell as LocalSystem.

Comment: I used that and jenkins started but my all jobs are gone .I already have the path of jenkins home in enviorment varaibles .Where all my jobs gone..??

Comment: @akshayjain sure: go on with Jenkins. I was just adding a way to execute the `cleartool endview -server` from command line with the LocalSystem account;

Comment: @akshayjain your question is about `cleartool endview -server` from command-line: let's solve that first.